# Bootstrap Version to use today? ASP.Net Core MVC Apps

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-5

So I'm building a new site attempting to use current latest libraries.  One of the issues I seem to be running into is Bootstrap 5.0 through 5.2 at least seem to not be fully working for things like Dropdowns or at the very least, finding examples for what I need aren't out there.

For example, just a simple drop down list, I couldn't find a straight forward sample as something about Bootstrap 5 integrated some of the jquery used by Bootstrap in prior versions into the Bootstrap.bundle libraries.  Can't recall where I read that, but removing all jquery scripts fixed my basic dropdown initial need.

However now I'm trying to find examples and guides for a Dropdown with Checkbox items and there doesn't seem to be any Bootstrap related examples or references later than Bootstrap 4.x versions.

So is it still better to use 4.x versions of Bootstrap currently?

Comment: Please see [ask]. We're not a discussion forum and your question is highly subjective.

Comment: That said, I doubt you'll find many folks willing to suggest that you build with a library which [reached end of life](https://github.com/twbs/release) six months ago. Bootstrap 5 is already more than three years old, so it's odd that you're having difficulty. Maybe post a more specific question about that.